# Организация мониторинга сетей организации на OpenBSD

Tags: сервер, администрирование, мониторинг, openbsd

Есть проблема по выбору правильного софта и настройки для мониторинга сетей целой компании с более чем 500+ ип адрессов.

Имеется сервер на OpenBSD, которому требуется сделать мониторинг более чем 500+ серверов в реал-тайме и каждый день в конце рабочего дня отправлять отчет по всем серверам с логами, где будет написано со скольки часов до скольки не работали некоторые IP адрессf.

Если не ошибаюсь то Nagios имела такую возможность, не когда не приходилось настраиваить..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему любая более-менее современная система мониторинга умеет просто проверять доступность хостов и отображать их графически (например). Только для nagios, если не ошибаюсь, нужен какой-нибудь модуль, а, например, [zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com), умеет это из коробки.

Comment: ошибаетесь, nagios это делает из коробки. Только сконфигурировать сервера нужно

Comment: @maint не спорю, я просто очень-очень давно последний раз эксплуатировал nagios+mrtg, с тех пор я полностью перешёл на zabbix, а за развитием nagios, к сожалению, перестал наблюдать.

Comment: Спасибо. Скорее я тоже выберу zabbix.